# Tokenize Function Not Working As Expected - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, optimization, code-organization

**These are the instructions:**

Write a function `tokenize(input_string)` that takes a string containing an expression and returns a list of tokens. Tokens in this small language will be delimited by whitespace, and so any time there a space (or several spaces in a row) in the input string, we want to split around that.

You should not use the built-in string operation split, but rather should structure your code using the tools we have developed so far.

When all is said and done, For example, running the tokenizer on this string:
`tokenize("2 2 + 3 4 / .5 0.2 3.2 + - COS")`

should return:
`['2', '2', '+', '3', '4', '/', '.5', '0.2', '3.2', '+', '-', 'COS']`

**This is my code:**

```
def tokenize(input_string):
    tokens = []
    token = ""
    for char in input_string:
        if char == " " and input_string[-1] != char and token != "":
            tokens.append(token)
            token = ""
        elif input_string[-1] == char:
            tokens.append(token + char)
        elif char != " ":
            token += char
    return tokens
```

My code works properly with the given example and similar arguments, but when i run something like:
`tokenize("pi load store load")`

i get:
`['pi', 'load', 'loa', 'store', 'load']` 
What's the bug? Tried finding it with print statements in various parts of the function to no avail. Also any advice on how to better organize the if statements will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: first fix your indention.

Comment: You ask what is the bug but you don't say what you are expecting to see with `tokenize("pi load store load")`

Comment: `input_string[-1]` isn't what you think it is

Comment: What does your function return for the string `"22 + 2"`? You'll find that doesn't work either, and may give you some hints

Comment: And what are the "tools we have developed so far"? You don't seem to be using any

Answer (score 0):

I think your flaw is in the line `elif input_string[-1] == char:`.

If I'm understanding you correctly, you are trying to use this `elif` case to check if you are at the end of the string, and if you are, to add the last token in the string to your list of tokens.

However, if you have the last character in your string appear more than once, it will go into this case every time; that's why you have both `'loa'` and `'load'` in your list.

My suggestion is to remove all of your checks for the current character being the same as the last character in the string, and add

```
if token != "":
    tokens.append(token)
```

after your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the Izaak Weiss answer, please simplify your logic about the checks, this could be a solution:

```
def tokenize(input_string):
    tokens = []
    token = ''
    for char in input_string:
        if char == ' ': # Possible token termination
            if token != '':
                tokens.append(token)
                token = ''
        else:
            token += char

    # Last token
    if token != '':
        tokens.append(token) 

    return tokens
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 approaches:

- The "plain" one that you were attempting to implement (tokenizing the string "manually")
- A little bit more advanced one that uses [[Python]: str.**find**(*sub*[, *start*[, *end*]])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) (also `rfind`)

Of course there are others as well (e.g. ones that use recursion, or even *regular expressions*), but they probably are too advanced.

```
def tokenize_plain(input_string):
    tokens = list()
    current_token = ""
    for char in input_string:
        if char == " ":
            if current_token:
                tokens.append(current_token)
                current_token = ""
        else:
            current_token += char
    if current_token:
        tokens.append(current_token)
    return tokens


def tokenize_find(input_string):
    tokens = list()
    start = 0
    end = input_string.find(" ", start)
    while end != -1:
        if end == start:
            start += 1
        else:
            tokens.append(input_string[start: end])
            start = end
        end = input_string.find(" ", start)
    end = input_string.rfind(" ", start)
    if end == -1:
        tokens.append(input_string[start:])
    else:
        tokens.append(input_string[start: end])
    return tokens


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for tokenize in [tokenize_plain, tokenize_find]:
        for text in ["pi load store load", "2 2 + 3 4 / .5 0.2 3.2 + - COS"]:
            print("{}('{}') = {}".format(tokenize.__name__, text, tokenize(text)))
```

**Output**:

> ```
> c:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q46372240>c:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe a.py
> tokenize_plain('pi load store load') = ['pi', 'load', 'store', 'load']
> tokenize_plain('2 2 + 3 4 / .5 0.2 3.2 + - COS') = ['2', '2', '+', '3', '4', '/', '.5', '0.2', '3.2', '+', '-', 'COS']
> tokenize_find('pi load store load') = ['pi', 'load', 'store', 'load']
> tokenize_find('2 2 + 3 4 / .5 0.2 3.2 + - COS') = ['2', '2', '+', '3', '4', '/', '.5', '0.2', '3.2', '+', '-', 'COS']
> ```

Comment: I think that your answer using python built-in functions is not allowed here, because probably the statement that says "You should not use the built-in string operation split, but rather should structure your code using the tools we have developed so far" means to do everything with plain python. In this case your tokenize_plain, that's equals to my answer, will probably be the solution for this.

Comment: @GabrielAvellaneda: It's a matter of technicality here. _"You should not use the built-in string operation split"_ is the only forbidden rule, and `tokenize_find` doesn't break it. But anyway, I was developing my answers (while you came up with yours), so I had to have smth extra... The "manual" string tokenize problem is "common knowledge" (at least I used the same approach 10+ years ago for a job interveiew)